# unexpected GetType() result for entity entry

Tags: c#, entity-framework, ef-code-first, dbcontext, objectstatemanager

While I iterating through `ObjectStateEntries` I expected `[t]` variable name will be `MY_ENTITY`

```
foreach (ObjectStateEntry entry in context.ObjectStateManager.GetObjectStateEntries(EntityState.Deleted))
{
    Type t = entry.Entity.GetType();
    ...
}
```

but real I have

```
System.Data.Entity.DynamicProxies.MY_ENTITY_vgfg7s7wyd7c7vgvgv.....
```

How can I determine can I cast current entry to `MY_ENTITY` type?

Comment: Have you tried to compare using the `is` keyword?

Answer (score 57, accepted):

You can get the original entity type of a proxy type by

```
ObjectContext.GetObjectType(entity.GetType())
```

This is a [static method of `ObjectContext`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.objects.objectcontext.getobjecttype.aspx), so you can readily use in in a `DbContext` environment.

If for some reason you need the actual entity as its original type you can use the pattern

```
var entity = entry.Entity as MyEntity;
if (entity != null)
{
    ...
}
```

This is slightly more efficient than

```
if (entry.Entity is MyEntity)
{
    var entity = (MyEntity)entry.Entity;
    ...
}
```

because the latter snippet casts the object twice.

Comment: A very good reason for needing to know the original type is for overriding `Equals()`, as the standard `GetType()` returns the proxy, which is not the same as the underlying type.

Comment: The (should have been) obvious fact that the method is static was completely lost on me until you pointed it out!

Comment: Of course, now you can do `if (entry.Entity is myEntity entity) { ... }` which will declare and assign `entity`

Answer (score 10):

You can use

```
Type t = entry.Entity.GetType().BaseType;
```

or

```
ObjectContext.GetObjectType(entity.GetType())
```

But the `second` way is a **better** way from my point of view. If you call Type() request inside a Mapper method, for example DTO mapper (from entity object to DTO class or from in-memory objects to DTO class), `ObjectContext.GetObjectType(..)`  will grant you **always** the expected result contrary to what will `.GetType().BaseType`

For example, if you use a [TPT (Table per Type)](http://weblogs.asp.net/manavi/inheritance-mapping-strategies-with-entity-framework-code-first-ctp5-part-2-table-per-type-tpt) strategy for EF Entity Model, call BaseType() on in-memory object will return the base class in hierarchy contrary to what will `ObjectContext.GetObjectType(..)`

[image]

Answer (score 5):

Another way is to access the `BaseType` property of the returned proxy type:

```
Type t = entry.Entity.GetType().BaseType;
```

Comment: I initially went with this answer as it looks neater (more self contained than needing ObjectContext around) than the accepted answer.  However, there is a potential problem depending on the scenario.  If you are adding an entity, it's not a proxy type yet, but just a POCO type.  Therefore, calling BaseType on it returns 'object'.  If you are only working with proxy types, such as if it's just dealing with entities retrieved from DB then no problem, but if it could be POCO or proxy, such as if collection has unsaved entities, using ObjectConext is the only safe option as Enrico explains below.