# Get DisplayName of class from it's DbEntityEntry object

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I'm looking to track my modified database entries following this [blog post](https://www.exceptionnotfound.net/entity-change-tracking-using-dbcontext-in-entity-framework-6/).

I have this class:

```
[DisplayName("PrettyNameForClass")]
public class UglyClassName
{
...
}
```

And when I'm saving down the I would like to save down the `PrettyNameForClass` instead of the `ClassName`. 
The code used to get the `ClassName`

The code I'm currently using:

```
var modifiedEntities = ChangeTracker.Entries()
        .Where(p => p.State == EntityState.Modified).ToList();

    foreach (var change in modifiedEntities)
    {
        var entityName = change.Entity.GetType().Name;
        var primaryKey = GetPrimaryKeyValue(change);
```

Comment: maybe this could help... http://stackoverflow.com/a/2656211/1706578 Its just an attribute

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer is basically, to get the associated attributes by `Type.GetCustomAttributes` and determine the configured `DisplayName`.

The following code does this. The second parameter on `GetCustomAttributes` tells to look into the inheritance hierarchy. Pro: get the attribute even if the entity type is a proxy type; Contra: if the entity type inherits a base class with DisplayNameAttribute set, the result may be unexpected.

```
var type = entity.GetType();
var name = type.GetCustomAttributes(typeof(DisplayNameAttribute), true)
    .Select(x => ((DisplayNameAttribute)x).DisplayName)
    .DefaultIfEmpty(type.Name)
    .First(); // what if more names are available for some reason?
```

In short, it's up to you if and how you want to handle the proxy / baseclass problem. Other than that, the solution should work.

**Edit** in order to avoid the proxy / baseclass problem, you can try

```
var type = ObjectContext.GetObjectType(entity.GetType());
```

This should resolve the actual type in case that entity is a proxy type. Then `type.GetCustomAttributes(typeof(DisplayNameAttribute), false)` can be used to check for the attribute only on the actual type without its base types.

Note, i didn't check this, only took it from [this Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16004707/unexpected-gettype-result-for-entity-entry)

Comment: This does exactly what I wanted and I don't see a scenario where there would be more than one `DisplayName`. Very good and elaborate answer

Comment: Worth noting as well with the code from the edited answer the `DefaultIfEmpty` should be changed to `DefaultIfEmpty(entity.Entity.GetType().Name)` otherwise it will `name` will be `DbEntityEntry` when no `DisplayName` is specified

Comment: I can edit `entity` into `change.Entity`, thought it would be obvious that `entity` represents this in the answer.

Comment: Yes ofc, that's not what I tried to point out. Before you edited your answer `DefaultIfEmpty(type.Name)` returns the name of the class but using the edited answer `DefaultIfEmpty(type.Name)` returns `DbEntityEntry`