# Unable to get Namespace from ObjectStateEntry when saving from a ViewController

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, dbcontext, audit-logging

I'm attempting to create an Audit Log for my MVC, Entity Framework website project.  I've been able to subscribe to `SaveChanges()` in my DBContext (and save to my database through another DBContext but same database).

My two questions in the end are:

- What does `if (!entry.IsRelationship)` do exactly? I have a ViewModel that calculates this as `True` when Saving and another as `False`. I would expect this to move into the rest of my method to save in the Audit Log.
- How can I get the full Namespace of my Object being modified?  I was using this: `entry.Entity.ToString()` but doesn't seem to work when Saving/Editing from a View Model (details below)

Here is a basic setup that I have thus far (`Album` object/controller works, but `AlbumView` doesn't):

Ablum class:

```
public class Album : BaseObject //BaseObject has a few properties, one is Oid (Guid)
{
    public string Name { get; set; }

    [Column(TypeName = "varchar(MAX)")]
    [DataType(DataType.MultilineText)]
    public string Description { get; set; }

    [Display(Name="Genres")]
    public virtual ICollection<AlbumsGenres> AlbumGenres { get; set; }

    [Display(Name="Artists")]
    public virtual ICollection<AlbumsArtists> AlbumArtists { get; set; }
}
```

AblumView class:

```
public class AlbumView
{
    [ScaffoldColumn(false)]
    public Guid Oid { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public string Name { get; set; }

    [Column(TypeName = "varchar(MAX)")]
    [DataType(DataType.MultilineText)]
    public string Description { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Genres")]
    public virtual List<AlbumsGenres> AlbumGenres { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Artists")]
    public virtual List<AlbumsArtists> AlbumArtists { get; set; }

}
```

AlbumsController (Audit works with something like this):

```
public ActionResult Edit(Album album)
{
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        db.Entry(album).State = EntityState.Modified;
        db.SaveChanges(); //This is where SaveChanges() takes over (see below)
        return RedirectToAction("Index");
    }
    return View(album);
}
```

AlbumsViewController:

```
public ActionResult Edit(Guid id, AlbumView albumViewModel)
{
    //Omitting setup...

    //Album gets updated
    Album album = db.Albums.Find(id);
    album.Name = albumViewModel.Name;
    album.Description = albumViewModel.Description;

    //Other Objects are also updated, just an example:
    albumArtists = new AlbumsArtists();
    albumArtists.Oid = Guid.NewGuid();
    albumArtists.Album = db.Albums.Find(id);
    albumArtists.Artist = db.Artists.Find(item.Artist.Oid);

    //In the end it calls:
    db.SaveChanges();

    //Omitting other stuff...
}
```

On db.SaveChanges() within my DbContext:

```
public class ApplicationDBContext : DbContext
{
    public ApplicationDBContext() : base("name=DefaultConnection") { }

    public System.Data.Entity.DbSet<ContentPub.Models.Music.Album> Albums { get; set; }
    //Other DBSet objects...

    public DbSet Set(string name)
    {
        return base.Set(Type.GetType(name));
    }

    public override int SaveChanges()
    {
        ApplicationLogDBContext logDb = new ApplicationLogDBContext();
        ChangeTracker.DetectChanges();

        ObjectContext ctx = ((IObjectContextAdapter)this).ObjectContext;

        List<ObjectStateEntry> objectStateEntryList =
            ctx.ObjectStateManager.GetObjectStateEntries(EntityState.Added
                                                       | EntityState.Modified
                                                       | EntityState.Deleted)
            .ToList();

        foreach (ObjectStateEntry entry in objectStateEntryList)
        {
            Guid oid = Guid.Empty;

            try
            {
                if (!entry.IsRelationship) //I don't understand this (first of my two questions)
                {
                    switch (entry.State)
                    {
                        //Removed other cases

                        case EntityState.Modified:
                        {
                            oid = (Guid)entry.EntityKey.EntityKeyValues[0].Value;

                            //This is the area that I am having issues (second of the two questions)

                            //Below will work when I call db.SaveChanges() from the AlbumsController, 
                            //'entry.Entity.ToString()' will get 'x.Models.Music.Albums' and begin a query

                                var query = this.Set(entry.Entity.ToString()).AsNoTracking().Where("Oid == @0", oid);

                            //The issue with the above is when I have a ViewModel, returns something like
                            // = System.Data.Entity.DynamicProxies.Album_AF81C390156ACC8283ECEC668AFB22C4AD621EF70F8F64641D56852D19755BF3

                            //If the proper Namespace is returned, the next line works and Audit continues
                            var query = this.Set(entry.EntitySet.ElementType.ToString()).AsNoTracking().Where("Oid == @0", oid);

                            //Does a bunch of AuditLog stuff if the above issue doesn't fail
                            break;
                        }
                    }
                }

            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                throw new Exception("Log Error (" + entry.Entity.ToString() + ") - " + ex.ToString());
            }
        }
        return base.SaveChanges();
    }
}
```

`entry.Entity.ToString()` will return something like:

```
System.Data.Entity.DynamicProxies.Album_AF81C390156ACC8283ECEC668AFB22C4AD621EF70F8F64641D56852D19755BF3
```

In the AlbumView I am updating Album, and a bunch of other Objects.  Not sure why it isn't returning `x.Models.Music.Albums`, is there a work-around, can someone explain or point me to other resources that I haven't found yet?

Comment: Try with [Audit.EntityFramework](https://github.com/thepirat000/Audit.NET/blob/master/src/Audit.EntityFramework/README.md) library. It could help.

Answer (score 1):

While it isn't the most efficient solution, it still is a solution for now.

I was able to do the following inside my `db.SaveChanges()` method:

```
//When AlbumView .BaseType was able to return x.Models.Music.Album
string strNamespace = entry.Entity.GetType().BaseType.ToString(); 

//Needed this if I was updating just an Object (ie: Album),
//would be nice to make something more concret
if (strNamespace == "x.Models.Core.BaseObject")
    strNamespace = entry.Entity.ToString();

//Continuing code
var query = this.Set(strNamespace).AsNoTracking().Where("Oid == @0", oid);
```

Found the answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16004707/unexpected-gettype-result-for-entity-entry#answer-31218807) from another Question that I had not found before posting this question