# How can you get the current View's Model name?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-views

I would expect this to be asked/answered a hundred times, but the only answer I can find anywhere on the entire Internet is:

```
var currentModel = Model.GetType().Name;
```

This ***almost*** works but for example if the Model is defined as

```
@model Myproject.Model.User_info
```

Then the value of currentModel ends up as something like this:

```
User_info_23L7HGAFWLIUHI7GLIUBGFWAKHGI73I37GArwq
```

Do I really have to strip off everything starting with the penultimate underscore?  Or is there a better way?

Comment: `Model.GetType().Name` should work. Is your model an Entity model?

Comment: Yes, but the string value comes out as pasted above with a GUID type of identifier appended with an underscore.

Comment: If you're working with the EF Proxy types then try [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16005340/2030565). The ObjectContext may now be in `System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Per Jasen's comment on the question above, the answer I ultimately went with was this:

```
var currentModel = System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ObjectContext.GetObjectType(Model.GetType()).Name;
```

... this reliably produces the correct name of both models and viewmodels as they are defined by the developer.